# Deactivate all layer except selected

Tags: 3d-view, layers, visibility

I was wondering if there is a way to automatically hide all layers except the selected one (in the same way <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> hides selected objects.

This is more useful than <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> shortcuts in some scenarios where you want to save visibility order of certain object groups through the view layer system.

[image]

Comment: CTRL + Click on the eye icon ? I doesn't work with the exclusion state (checkbox) though.

Comment: Yup, but it doesn't work with exclusion state as you mentioned, which would be better for organising complex viewsets. Going to float this to the Blender suggestions